# Animation using React-spring useTransition not working as expected inside a recursive loop

Tags: reactjs, spring, recursion, animation, css-transitions

I've been unable to apply a transition to divs in a comment section i'm working on. The comment section is recursively rendered and there's an instance of useTransition in each one. When the reply button to any of the comments is clicked, the reply form should transition in. Same thing when the show/hide comments is clicked, all its children should transition out however the transition effects are applied to all the divs. i've made a [codepen to illustrate the problem.](https://codepen.io/ziploker/pen/MWmpwLq?editors=0010) please point me in the right direction. Thank you.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react@17.0.1";
import * as ReactDOM from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react-dom@17.0.1";
import styled from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/styled-components@5.3.0";

import { useSpring, useTransition, animated } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react-spring@9.2.4";



/////////   Styled Components   ///////////////////////////////
  
const CommentDisplay = styled(animated.div)`

  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 25px;
  position: relative;
  
  img {
    
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin: 1px 10px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid gray;
  }

`;
  
  
const TopBarWrapper = styled.div`

    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;

`;
  
  
const BorderDiv = styled.div`

  position: absolute;
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  height: calc(100% - 25px);
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 12px;
  bottom: 0px;
  pointer-events: none;

`;
  
  
const CommentBody = styled.p`
    
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  -ms-word-break: break-all;
  word-break: break-word;
  padding-left: 35px;

`;
  
  
const BottomBarWrapper = styled.div`

  grid-area: bottomBar;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-left: 35px;

`;
  
  
const Reply = styled.div`
    
  color: rgba(7, 7, 7, 0.65);
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 0px;
  font-size: 14px;

  &:hover{
    color: black;
  }

`;
  
  
const VoteUp = styled.div`
    
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px;

  &:hover{
    background-color: #e5f4fb;
  }

  svg{
    width: 16px;
    height: 15px;
    margin-right: 4px;
  }

  span{
    font-size: 13px;
  }

`;


const VoteDown = styled.div`
    
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px;

  &:hover{
    background-color: #e5f4fb;
  }

  svg{
    width: 16px;
    height: 15px;
    margin-right: 4px;
  }

  span{
    font-size: 13px;
  }
`;
  
  
const Form = styled.form`

  display: grid;
  //grid-template-columns: 90%;
  grid-gap: 1.5rem;
  
  grid-area: main_comment_body;

`;


const FormWrapper = styled.div`

  display: ${props => props.rows[props.commentid] == "true" ? "grid" : "grid"};
  grid-template-columns: minmax(min-content, max-content) 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: minmax(50px, 1fr) minmax(min-content, max-content);
  grid-template-areas:

    "main_comment_img      main_comment_body  "
    "main_comment_img     main_comment_buttons";


  margin: 0px 50px 0px 85px;
  z-index: ${props => props.rows[props.commentid] == "true" ? "1" : "-1"};
  opacity: ${props => props.rows[props.commentid] == "true" ? "1" : "0"};
  height: ${props => props.rows[props.commentid] == "true" ? "initial" : "0px"};
  min-height: ${props => props.rows[props.commentid] == "true" ? "100px" : "0px"};
  

  position: relative;
  top: ${props => props.rows[props.commentid] == "true" ? "7px" : "-100px"};
  left: 0;
  background-color: F4F4F4;
  transition: all .05s ease 0s;

  img {
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      grid-area: avatar;
      margin: 1px 10px 0px 0px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 1px solid gray;


      grid-Area: main_comment_img;
      
  }
`;




const CommentSection = () => {
  
  
  
//in the useEffect hook, an ajax call gets all the comments from the rails server (in this case, it's a hard coded //"allComments" object below) and recursivley gets the id of every comment, reply, reply of reply etc.. and builds an //object in the format of {"comment id" : " false"}.  
//  
// example showMore initial state  
//   {"207":"false",
//   "208":"false",
//   "209":"false",
//   "210":"false",
//   "211":"false",
//   "212":"false",
//   "213":"false",
//   "214":"false"}
//  
//  when the "show/hide" comments button is clicked, it sets the id of all its children to "true" in the showMore state //variable, causing the css to //toggle it out of view. 
  
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState({});
  const [rows, setRows] = useState({});
  
 // "rows" is identical to "showMore" but is used when the "reply" button in clicked, causing the reply form appear.
  
  
  
  //response from server containing all the comments and its nested replies etc..
  const allComments = [
        {
            "id": 295,
            "body": "This is a First level comment to the main Story blah blah...",
            "created_at": "2021-07-16T17:17:10.410Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-07-16T17:17:10.410Z",
            "original_comment_author": null,
            "parent_id": null,
            "ancestry": null,
            "date": "less than a minute",
            "comment_number": 256,
            "reply": false,
            "user_id": 1,
            "commentable_type": "Story",
            "commentable_id": 1,
            "edit_history": "",
            "author_avatar": "undefined",
            "author_nick": "Jimmy",
            "comments": [
                {
                    "id": 296,
                    "body": "this is the first reply to the main comment ",
                    "created_at": "2021-07-16T17:17:49.585Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-07-16T17:17:49.585Z",
                    "original_comment_author": "undefined",
                    "parent_id": 295,
                    "ancestry": "295",
                    "date": "less than a minute",
                    "comment_number": 257,
                    "reply": true,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "commentable_type": "Comment",
                    "commentable_id": 295,
                    "edit_history": "",
                    "author_avatar": "undefined",
                    "author_nick": "izzy",
                    "comments": [
                        {
                            "id": 298,
                            "body": "Reply to the reply (3rd level)",
                            "created_at": "2021-07-16T17:22:46.088Z",
                            "updated_at": "2021-07-16T17:22:46.088Z",
                            "original_comment_author": "undefined",
                            "parent_id": 296,
                            "ancestry": "295/296",
                            "date": "less than a minute",
                            "comment_number": 259,
                            "reply": true,
                            "user_id": 1,
                            "commentable_type": "Comment",
                            "commentable_id": 296,
                            "edit_history": "",
                            "author_avatar": "undefined",
                            "author_nick": "Noel",
                            "comments": [
                                {
                                    "id": 299,
                                    "body": "another reply to a reply (4th level) etc...",
                                    "created_at": "2021-07-16T17:23:10.561Z",
                                    "updated_at": "2021-07-16T17:23:10.561Z",
                                    "original_comment_author": "undefined",
                                    "parent_id": 298,
                                    "ancestry": "295/296/298",
                                    "date": "less than a minute",
                                    "comment_number": 260,
                                    "reply": true,
                                    "user_id": 1,
                                    "commentable_type": "Comment",
                                    "commentable_id": 298,
                                    "edit_history": "",
                                    "author_avatar": "undefined",
                                    "author_nick": "Mitch",
                                    "comments": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 297,
                    "body": "this is a second reply to the main comment .... ",
                    "created_at": "2021-07-16T17:18:59.249Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-07-16T17:18:59.249Z",
                    "original_comment_author": "undefined",
                    "parent_id": 295,
                    "ancestry": "295",
                    "date": "less than a minute",
                    "comment_number": 258,
                    "reply": true,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "commentable_type": "Comment",
                    "commentable_id": 295,
                    "edit_history": "",
                    "author_avatar": "undefined",
                    "author_nick": "mike",
                    "comments": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 294,
            "body": "This is another First Level comment to the main story ... ",
            "created_at": "2021-07-16T17:16:19.314Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-07-16T17:16:19.314Z",
            "original_comment_author": null,
            "parent_id": null,
            "ancestry": null,
            "date": "less than a minute",
            "comment_number": 255,
            "reply": false,
            "user_id": 1,
            "commentable_type": "Story",
            "commentable_id": 1,
            "edit_history": "",
            "author_avatar": "undefined",
            "author_nick": "Natalie",
            "comments": []
        }
    ]
;
  
  
  useEffect( () => {
    
    addAllCommentsToStateForReplyButtonToWork(allComments)
    addAllCommentsToStateForShowMoreButtonToWork(allComments)
    
  },[]);

  
  

  const getReplyArray = (childrenCommentArray) => {

    let tempArray = []

    childrenCommentArray.map( (x, i) => {

      x.id
      tempArray.push(x.id + ", ")

    });

    return tempArray.length > 0 ? tempArray : "blank"


  };

  function addAllCommentsToStateForReplyButtonToWork(c) {

    let newArray = [];
    let newState = {};

    function getAllId(arr, key) {


      arr.forEach(function(item) {

        for (let keys in item) {

          if (keys === key) {
            newArray.push(item[key])
          } else if (Array.isArray(item[keys])) {
            getAllId(item[keys], key);
          }
        }

      });

    }

    getAllId(c, 'id');

    newArray.forEach(function(item) {

      newState[item] = "false";

    })

    setRows(newState);

  }  

  function addAllCommentsToStateForShowMoreButtonToWork(c) {

    let newArray = [];
    let newState = {};

    function getAllId(arr, key) {


      arr.forEach(function(item) {

        for (let keys in item) {

          if (keys === key) {
            newArray.push(item[key])
          } else if (Array.isArray(item[keys])) {
            getAllId(item[keys], key)
          }
        }

      })

    }

    getAllId(c, 'id')

    newArray.forEach(function(item) {

      newState[item] = "false"

    })

    setShowMore(newState);

  }
  
  const handleSubmitClick = (e) => {
    
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  const hideCommentsOrShowComments = (childrenCommentArray) => {


    
    let tempArray = []
    let numOfTrue = 0
    let numOfFalse = 0
    let tempShowMore = {}
    
    childrenCommentArray.map( (x, i) => {

      tempArray.push(x.id)

    })


    tempArray.forEach (x => {

      if (showMore[x] == "true"){

        numOfTrue = numOfTrue + 1

      }else{
        
        numOfFalse = numOfFalse + 1

      }

    })

    if (numOfTrue > 0){

      return "show replies"
    
    }else{
      
      return "hide replies"
    }


  }
  
  const handleShowMoreButton = (childrenCommentArray) => {


        //console.log("handleShowMoreButtonfrom article.jsx------------------------")
                    
        
        let tempArray = []
        let tempShowMore = {}
        childrenCommentArray.map( (x, i) => {
            
        

            
            tempArray.push(x.id)
            
        
        
        
        })
    
        
        tempArray.forEach (x => {

            //console.log("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx idididid" + x)
            if (showMore[x] == "true"){
                
                //console.log("in if and x is = " + x + " and was true, changing it!")
                
                tempShowMore[x] = "false"
    
            }else{
                //console.log("in else and x is = " + x + " and was false, changing it!")
               
                tempShowMore[x] = "true"
    
            }





        } )

        setShowMore({...showMore, ...tempShowMore})

    }
  
  const handleReplyButton = (id) => {

        

       if (rows[id] == "true"){
            setRows({...rows, [id]: "false"})

       }else{

        setRows({...rows,[id]: "true"})

       }

       

        
        
    }
  
  const handleChange = () => {
    
    
    //
  }
  
  

  
  ////////////// Comment Function, Called recursively ///////////////
  function Comment({ item, rows, showMore, handleShowMoreButton, handleReplyButton }){
    
    
    const transition = useTransition(showMore[item.id], {
           
      from: {opacity: 0},
      enter: {y: 0, opacity: 1},
      leave: {opacity: 0},
      delay: 100
            
    });
    
        
    const nestedComments = (item.comments || []).map(com => {

      return <Comment style={{border: "2px solid blue"}} key={com.id} item={com} type="child" rows={rows} 
               showMore={showMore} handleShowMoreButton={handleShowMoreButton} 
               handleReplyButton={handleReplyButton}/>

    });

        
    return (
            
      <>

        {transition((style,val) => val == "true" ? '' : 
            
          <CommentDisplay 
            style={style} 
            key={item.id + "commentDisplay"} 
            showMore={showMore} 
            item={item} 
            id={item.id} >

                        
            <BorderDiv/>
                    
                        
            <TopBarWrapper>
              
              <img src={item.author_avatar}/>
              
              <h3 style={{alignSelf: "center", fontSize: ".6em", gridArea: "nick", marginRight: "8px"}}>                                   {item.author_nick}
              </h3>
              
              <span style={{alignSelf: "center", gridArea: "date", fontSize: ".6em", color: "gray"}}></span>
                        
                            
            </TopBarWrapper>
                        
            <CommentBody style={{gridArea: "body", fontSize: "15px"}}>
              {item.body} (...the ID for this comment => {item.id}, and its children id's => {getReplyArray(item.comments)})                                    </CommentBody>
                      
            <BottomBarWrapper>
                
              <Reply onClick={() => handleReplyButton(item.id)}>reply</Reply>
                            
              <VoteUp>
            
                <svg viewBox="0 0 22 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path key={item.id + "path1"} data-id={ item.id + "path1"} d="M10.74.04a2.013 2.013 0 00-1.58 1.88c-.11 2.795-.485 4.45-2.283 6.946a1.272 1.272 0 00-1.065-.58h-4.55C.573 8.287 0 8.84 0 9.507v8.773c0 .667.572 1.218 1.263 1.218h4.55c.435 0 .821-.22 1.049-.548.263.204.506.387.758.533.417.24.887.384 1.532.45 1.29.128 3.403.032 8.283.052a.53.53 0 00.317-.113c1.224-.667 4.255-5.775 4.248-10.534-.026-1.138-.542-1.78-1.532-1.78H13.96c.388-2.47.131-4.738-.735-6.208C12.76.555 12.078.111 11.403.018a2.035 2.035 0 00-.663.022m2.154 7.912c-.055.28.201.58.498.58h6.934c.356.035.67.091.67.913 0 1.047-.168 2.886-1.031 5.057-.865 2.172-2.155 4.531-2.603 4.455-1.215.08-7.014.109-8.108 0-.556-.056-.818-.135-1.113-.306-.266-.152-.59-.423-1.066-.791v-7.6c2.349-2.88 2.979-5.302 3.096-8.3.338-1.495 1.702-1.082 2.179-.13.697 2.402.879 4.442.544 6.122M1.263 9.262h4.55c.148 0 .251.1.251.244v8.773c0 .144-.103.243-.252.243h-4.55c-.148 0-.251-.099-.251-.243V9.506c0-.144.103-.244.252-.244"></path>
                
                </svg>

                <span></span>
                            
              </VoteUp>
                
              <VoteDown>
                <svg viewBox="0 0 22 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path key={item.id + "path2"} data-id={ item.id + "path2"} d="M11.26 19.96a2.013 2.013 0 001.58-1.881c.11-2.794.484-4.45 2.282-6.945.224.345.618.58 1.066.58h4.548c.692 0 1.264-.553 1.264-1.22V1.722c0-.668-.572-1.22-1.264-1.22h-4.548c-.436 0-.823.22-1.05.55a6.898 6.898 0 00-.759-.534c-.416-.24-.887-.384-1.531-.45C11.558-.06 9.445.037 4.564.017a.521.521 0 00-.316.114C3.023.796-.007 5.904 0 10.663c.025 1.138.541 1.78 1.532 1.78H8.04c-.39 2.47-.131 4.738.735 6.208.467.794 1.148 1.238 1.823 1.331a2.034 2.034 0 00.663-.022m-2.155-7.913c.056-.28-.202-.579-.497-.579H1.674c-.356-.035-.67-.091-.67-.913 0-1.047.166-2.886 1.031-5.057C2.9 3.326 4.19.967 4.638 1.044c1.214-.081 7.014-.109 8.108 0 .556.055.818.134 1.113.305.265.152.59.423 1.066.791v7.6c-2.349 2.88-2.979 5.302-3.096 8.3-.338 1.495-1.702 1.083-2.179.13-.697-2.402-.88-4.442-.545-6.123m11.631-1.309h-4.548c-.149 0-.252-.1-.252-.244V1.722c0-.144.103-.244.252-.244h4.548c.15 0 .253.1.253.244v8.772c0 .144-.103.244-.253.244"></path>                     </svg>                                
                                
                <span></span>

              </VoteDown>
                            
                
                <span style={{cursor: "pointer", marginLeft: "10px", fontSize: "10px", lineHeight: "40px"}} 
                onClick={() => handleShowMoreButton(item.comments)}> 
                
                  {item.comments === undefined || item.comments.length == 0 ? "" :                                                           hideCommentsOrShowComments(item.comments)} 
              
                </span>

                      
            </BottomBarWrapper>
                      
                      
                      
            <FormWrapper rows={rows} commentid={item.id}>
        
              <img src={item.author_avatar}></img>

              <Form 
                id={item.id.toString() + "form"} 
                className="form-inline" 
                onSubmit={handleSubmitClick} 
                enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        
        
                <div style={{width: "100%", height: "100%"}} className="field" >
                  
                  <textarea 
                    style={{width: "100%"}}
                    onChange={handleChange} 
                    index={1}
                    placeholder={"...reply to " }
                    name="comment"
                    onKeyPress={e => {
                    
                      if(e.key === 'Enter')
                        e.preventDefault()
                    }}
            
                    value={"enter a reply..."}/>
                </div>
        
              </Form>
      
              <button 
                form={item.id.toString() + "form"} 
                style={{marginTop: "3px", gridArea: "main_comment_buttons"}} 
                type="submit">
                
                reply now
              </button>
            
            </FormWrapper>
                            
            {nestedComments}

          </CommentDisplay>
                            
        )}
                
      </>
   )
}
  
  
  
  return (
                
      
    <div style={{margin: "0 auto 90px auto"}}>
      
      <div style={{background: "#d3f7b9"}}>
        
        <ul style={{padding: "18px", margin: "0px 15px 0px 15px", width: "80vw"}}>
          <li> <h2>Animation using React-spring useTransition not working as expected. All the divs get animated instead of only the respective divs when the "show/hide comments" button or the "reply" buttons are clicked. </h2></li>
          
            <ul style={{margin: "10px 30px"}}>
              
              <li>Each top level comment is mapped into the Comment function (Line 715) </li><br/>
              
              <li>The Comment function (Line 548) recursively loops thru each top level comment's nested replies, replies of replies, replies of replies of replies etc.... adds useTansition to each and renders them.  </li><br/>
            
              <li> When the show/hide button is clicked, it changes the boolean state for all its children to true causing the children to collapse out of view. This is the part i want to animate. Same thing when the reply button is clicked, the reply form should be animated.</li><br/>
            
              
            </ul>
        </ul>
        
        
      </div>
      
      <div style={{position: "relative"}}>

        {allComments.map( (c) => {

          return (
            <Comment 
              key={c.id} 
              item={c} 
              rows={rows} 
              showMore={showMore} 
              handleShowMoreButton={handleShowMoreButton}
              handleReplyButton={handleReplyButton}/>
          )
        })}
      </div>    
    </div>
      
  )
}









class App extends React.Component {
  
  render() {
    return (
      
      
        <CommentSection/>
      
    );
  }
}





const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using an array of refs to animate the reply form and the show/hide button. It was all the setStates i had that were causing to many renders and didn't let the CSS transition animation to work.

[Link to working solution](https://codepen.io/ziploker/pen/zYwjjYB)

```
function CommentSection(props){

    
  //all the comments from server, usually in useeffect hook but hardcoded here instead
  const artDataComments = [
        {
            "id": 295,
            "body": "This is a First level comment to the main Story blah blah...",
            "created_at": "2021-07-16T17:17:10.410Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-07-16T17:17:10.410Z",
            "original_comment_author": null,
            "parent_id": null,
            "ancestry": null,
            "date": "less than a minute",
            "comment_number": 256,
            "reply": false,
            "user_id": 1,
            "commentable_type": "Story",
            "commentable_id": 1,
            "edit_history": "",
            "author_avatar": "undefined",
            "author_nick": "Jimmy",
            "comments": [
                {
                    "id": 296,
                    "body": "this is the first reply to the main comment ",
                    "created_at": "2021-07-16T17:17:49.585Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-07-16T17:17:49.585Z",
                    "original_comment_author": "undefined",
                    "parent_id": 295,
                    "ancestry": "295",
                    "date": "less than a minute",
                    "comment_number": 257,
                    "reply": true,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "commentable_type": "Comment",
                    "commentable_id": 295,
                    "edit_history": "",
                    "author_avatar": "undefined",
                    "author_nick": "izzy",
                    "comments": [
                        {
                            "id": 298,
                            "body": "Reply to the reply (3rd level)",
                            "created_at": "2021-07-16T17:22:46.088Z",
                            "updated_at": "2021-07-16T17:22:46.088Z",
                            "original_comment_author": "undefined",
                            "parent_id": 296,
                            "ancestry": "295/296",
                            "date": "less than a minute",
                            "comment_number": 259,
                            "reply": true,
                            "user_id": 1,
                            "commentable_type": "Comment",
                            "commentable_id": 296,
                            "edit_history": "",
                            "author_avatar": "undefined",
                            "author_nick": "Noel",
                            "comments": [
                                {
                                    "id": 299,
                                    "body": "another reply to a reply (4th level) etc...",
                                    "created_at": "2021-07-16T17:23:10.561Z",
                                    "updated_at": "2021-07-16T17:23:10.561Z",
                                    "original_comment_author": "undefined",
                                    "parent_id": 298,
                                    "ancestry": "295/296/298",
                                    "date": "less than a minute",
                                    "comment_number": 260,
                                    "reply": true,
                                    "user_id": 1,
                                    "commentable_type": "Comment",
                                    "commentable_id": 298,
                                    "edit_history": "",
                                    "author_avatar": "undefined",
                                    "author_nick": "Mitch",
                                    "comments": []
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "id": 297,
                    "body": "this is a second reply to the main comment .... ",
                    "created_at": "2021-07-16T17:18:59.249Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-07-16T17:18:59.249Z",
                    "original_comment_author": "undefined",
                    "parent_id": 295,
                    "ancestry": "295",
                    "date": "less than a minute",
                    "comment_number": 258,
                    "reply": true,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "commentable_type": "Comment",
                    "commentable_id": 295,
                    "edit_history": "",
                    "author_avatar": "undefined",
                    "author_nick": "mike",
                    "comments": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 294,
            "body": "This is another First Level comment to the main story ... ",
            "created_at": "2021-07-16T17:16:19.314Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-07-16T17:16:19.314Z",
            "original_comment_author": null,
            "parent_id": null,
            "ancestry": null,
            "date": "less than a minute",
            "comment_number": 255,
            "reply": false,
            "user_id": 1,
            "commentable_type": "Story",
            "commentable_id": 1,
            "edit_history": "",
            "author_avatar": "undefined",
            "author_nick": "Natalie",
            "comments": []
        }
    ]
;
    
  const allShowMoreRefs = useRef([]);
  allShowMoreRefs.current = []

  const allReplyRefs = useRef([]);
  allReplyRefs.current = []


  const getReplyArray = (childrenCommentArray) => {
    
        let tempArray = []
    
        childrenCommentArray.map( (x, i) => {
    
            x.id
            tempArray.push(x.id + ", ")
    
        })
    
        return tempArray.length > 0 ? tempArray : "blank"
    }
    
    
  const handleReplyButton = (childrenCommentArray, e, itemID) => {


    allReplyRefs.current.map ( (current, i) => {
      
      if (itemID == current.id.substr(0, current.id.indexOf('-'))){

        if (current.classList.contains("replyForm")){

          current.classList.remove("replyForm")
          
        }else{
          current.classList.add("replyForm")
          
        }

      }
    
    })

    

  }


  const handleShowMoreButton = (childrenCommentArray, e, itemID) => {


    //set the label
    if (e.target.innerText == "hide replies"){

      e.target.innerText = "show replies"

    }else{

      e.target.innerText = "hide replies"

    }



    //get the ref(s) and change the css
    childrenCommentArray.map(item => {

      allShowMoreRefs.current.map ( (current, i) => {


        if (item.id == current.id){

          if (current.classList.contains("shrink")){

            current.classList.remove("shrink")
          }else{
            current.classList.add("shrink")
          }


        }

      })

    })


        
    }

    
    

    
    
    
    //function called recursivley depended on how many nested comments get returned from server
  const Comment = ({ item, userState, storyID, setArtDataComments, handleShowMoreButton, handleReplyButton}) => {
    
    const addToShowMoreRefs = (el) => {
    
            if (el && !allShowMoreRefs.current.includes(el)){
                
                allShowMoreRefs.current.push(el)
                
            }
    
        }


    const addToReplyRefs = (el) => {
    
            //console.log("size b4 going in addToReplyeRefs is ", allReplyRefs.current.length )
            console.log("in================= addTo_Reply_Refs")
    
            if (el && !allReplyRefs.current.includes(el)){
                //console.log("inside================= addToReplyeRefs")
                //console.log(el)
                allReplyRefs.current.push(el)
                console.log("size after adding one is ", allReplyRefs.current.length )
            }
    
        }
        

    
    const nestedComments = (item.comments || []).map(com => {
    
      
      return (
        
        <div key={item.id}>
                    
          <Comment style={{border: "2px solid blue"}} 
            item={com} type="child" 
            userState={userState} 
            storyID={storyID} 
            setArtDataComments={setArtDataComments} 
            handleShowMoreButton={handleShowMoreButton} 
            handleReplyButton={handleReplyButton} />
                
        </div>
      )
    });
    
    
    
    return (
    
      <CommentDisplay 
        ref={addToShowMoreRefs} 
        className={"replies"} 
        key={item.id + "commentDisplay"} 
        item={item} id={item.id} >
    
        <BorderDiv/>
    
        <TopBarWrapper>
                        
          <img src="defaultAvatar"/>
              
          <h3 style={{alignSelf: "center", fontSize: ".6em", gridArea: "nick", marginRight: "8px"}}>
            {item.author_nick}
          </h3>
              
          <span style={{alignSelf: "center", gridArea: "date", fontSize: ".6em", color: "gray"}}></span>
  
        </TopBarWrapper>
    
        <CommentBody style={{gridArea: "body", fontSize: "15px"}}>
          {item.body} this comment ID is {item.id} and its children array is {getReplyArray(item.comments)}
        </CommentBody>
    
        
        <BottomBarWrapper>
    
          <Reply onClick={(e) => handleReplyButton(item.comments, e, item.id)}>reply</Reply>
    
            <VoteUp onClick={(e)=>{handleVoteUp(e, item.id)}}>
                  
              <svg viewBox="0 0 22 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path key={item.id + "path1"} data-id={ item.id + "path1"} 
                                                                            d="M10.74.04a2.013 2.013 0 00-1.58 1.88c-.11 2.795-.485 4.45-2.283 
                6.946a1.272 1.272 0 00-1.065-.58h-4.55C.573 8.287 0 8.84 0 9.507v8.773c0 .667.572 1.218 1.263 1.218h4.55c.435 0 .821-.22 1.049-.548.263.204.506.387.758.533.417.24.887.384 1.532.45 1.29.128 3.403.032 8.283.052a.53.53 0 00.317-.113c1.224-.667 4.255-5.775 4.248-10.534-.026-1.138-.542-1.78-1.532-1.78H13.96c.388-2.47.131-4.738-.735-6.208C12.76.555 12.078.111 11.403.018a2.035 2.035 0 00-.663.022m2.154 7.912c-.055.28.201.58.498.58h6.934c.356.035.67.091.67.913 0 1.047-.168 2.886-1.031 5.057-.865 2.172-2.155 4.531-2.603 4.455-1.215.08-7.014.109-8.108 0-.556-.056-.818-.135-1.113-.306-.266-.152-.59-.423-1.066-.791v-7.6c2.349-2.88 2.979-5.302 3.096-8.3.338-1.495 1.702-1.082 2.179-.13.697 2.402.879 4.442.544 6.122M1.263 9.262h4.55c.148 0 .251.1.251.244v8.773c0 .144-.103.243-.252.243h-4.55c-.148 0-.251-.099-.251-.243V9.506c0-.144.103-.244.252-.244"></path></svg>
              <span commentid={item.id}>{item.total_upvotes}</span>
    
            </VoteUp>
    
            <VoteDown onClick={(e)=>{handleVoteDown(e, item.id)}}>
                  
              <svg viewBox="0 0 22 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path key={item.id + "path2"} data-id={ item.id + "path2"} d="M11.26 19.96a2.013 2.013 0 001.58-1.881c.11-2.794.484-4.45 2.282-6.945.224.345.618.58 1.066.58h4.548c.692 0 1.264-.553 1.264-1.22V1.722c0-.668-.572-1.22-1.264-1.22h-4.548c-.436 0-.823.22-1.05.55a6.898 6.898 0 00-.759-.534c-.416-.24-.887-.384-1.531-.45C11.558-.06 9.445.037 4.564.017a.521.521 0 00-.316.114C3.023.796-.007 5.904 0 10.663c.025 1.138.541 1.78 1.532 1.78H8.04c-.39 2.47-.131 4.738.735 6.208.467.794 1.148 1.238 1.823 1.331a2.034 2.034 0 00.663-.022m-2.155-7.913c.056-.28-.202-.579-.497-.579H1.674c-.356-.035-.67-.091-.67-.913 0-1.047.166-2.886 1.031-5.057C2.9 3.326 4.19.967 4.638 1.044c1.214-.081 7.014-.109 8.108 0 .556.055.818.134 1.113.305.265.152.59.423 1.066.791v7.6c-2.349 2.88-2.979 5.302-3.096 8.3-.338 1.495-1.702 1.083-2.179.13-.697-2.402-.88-4.442-.545-6.123m11.631-1.309h-4.548c-.149 0-.252-.1-.252-.244V1.722c0-.144.103-.244.252-.244h4.548c.15 0 .253.1.253.244v8.772c0 .144-.103.244-.253.244"></path></svg>
              <span  commentid={item.id}>{item.total_downvotes}</span>
    
            </VoteDown>
    
            <span 
              style={{cursor: "pointer", marginLeft: "10px", fontSize: "10px", lineHeight: "40px"}} 
              onClick={(e) => handleShowMoreButton(item.comments, e, item.id)}> 
                    
                {item.comments === undefined || item.comments.length == 0 ? "" : "hide replies"}
            
            </span>

        </BottomBarWrapper>
    
                    
        <div 
          id={item.id + "-replyform"} 
          className={"replyFormHidden"} 
          ref={props.addToReplyRefs} 
          commentid={props.commentid}
          ref={addToReplyRefs}
          originalcommentAuthor={item.author_nick}
          userState={userState}
          storyID={storyID}
          commentid={item.id}
          setArtDataComments={setArtDataComments}
          handleReplyButton={handleReplyButton}>
                      
          <img src="defaultManIcon"></img>

          <Form 
            id={item.id + "form"} 
            className="form-inline" 
            onSubmit="handleAdd" 
            enctype="multipart/form-data" >

        
            <div style={{width: "100%", height: "100%"}} className="field" >
        
          
              <Textarea
                type="textarea"
                className="form-control"
                index={1}
                placeholder={"...reply to " + props.commentAuthor}
                name="comment"
                onKeyPress={e => {
                  if(e.key === 'Enter')
                    e.preventDefault()
                }}/>
              
            </div>

          </Form>

          <button 
            form={item.id + "form"} 
            style={{marginTop: "3px", gridArea: "main_comment_buttons"}} 
            type="submit" >

            reply now
          </button>
        </div>

                    
        {nestedComments}
    
      </CommentDisplay>

    )
  }
    
  return (
        
    <Comments>
          
      <div>

        <div style={{position: "relative"}}>
              
          {

            artDataComments.map( (c, i) => {

              return (

                <div key={c.id}>
                                    
                  <Comment 
                    item={c} 
                    userState={props.userState} 
                    handleShowMoreButton={handleShowMoreButton} 
                    handleReplyButton={handleReplyButton} />
                </div>
                                
              )
            })
          }
              
        </div>
            
      </div>

    </Comments>
    
  );
}
```